# remove days from Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the "agendaWeek" view of FullCalendar and I only have events on Sunday-Thursday.

Is there a way to remove that Friday and Saturday from the view completely?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think FullCalendar supports this. We could have put in a workaround in the month view to achieve this, but it is a bit hard to do so in the agenda views. You can turn off the weekends though - but I don't think that'll fit into what you need.

Comment: thanks ganeshk. if i can turn off saturday that's half way there :)  can you tell me how thats done for agendaWeek view?

Comment: You can use the `weekends` [option](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/weekends/). Be forewarned though, this applies to BOTH Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: mmm.. you are right - not what i want then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the option weekends=false, then you will need to edit the function (inside the lib) to exclude the days you want:

```
function skipWeekend(date, inc, excl) { ... }
```

After you need to edit the calls to this function inside week views:

```
function AgendaWeekView and BasicWeekView
```

Cheers,